# Transition freezes for a moment after moving a couple pixels - SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

I have a grid view with a floating button overlaid on top, which appears and disappears through the bottom edge (using `.transition(.move(edge: .bottom)`). However, when it disappears, a.k.a when it slides back down, it freezes for a second, and then goes all the way down. I've been trying to pinpoint the culprit, but I haven't found anything – it's not because I'm using an overlay, nor is it because of the safe area, and it's not due to the button's shape.

Here's a [screen recording](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=COGNN7Ga_mA) showing the button appearing and disappearing, and the momentary freezing.

And this is what my code looks like:

```swift
var body: some View {
    ScrollView {
        // ...
    }
    .overlay(alignment: .bottom) {
        VStack {          
            if condition {
                Button(action: { /* ... */ }) {
                    Text("Share")
                }
                .background { LinearGradient(...) }
                .clipShape(Capsule())
                .transition(.move(edge: .bottom))
            }
        }
        .animation(.linear, value: condition)
    }
}
```

Any idea why the transition momentarily freezes like this?

Comment: It does not freezing! It works as you coded! first transition happens, then you remove the view with a condition. PS: There is always a small delay between the end of transition and removing the view, the api works like that. Maybe apple would polishing the api in future to remove this small delay but right now it exist. I do not like it either and it is not needed, but maybe api use `DispatchQueue` undercover instead observing animation value.

Comment: Interesting - I hadn't thought about it that way. In what way would you want me to use `DispatchQueue`? Do you think I should control the button's vertical offset myself?

Comment: Do not forget using offset would help to reach the goal you want, but that delay would exist even user would not be able observe it.

Comment: I ended up just doing `.transition(.move(edge: .bottom).combined(with: .opacity))`, and it worked. Thanks anyways!